# Extending a map to a well defined homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, group-presentation

Given a map $f: S \rightarrow H$, with $S$ some set of generators, when and how can $f$ be extended to a well defined homomorphism with $\phi : G \rightarrow H $ with $G$ a group generated by $S$ with $\lbrace r_i \rbrace$ a  finite set of relations.

Further what requirements are needed to show that $\phi[G] = H$ and that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is the quotient of $F(S)$ the free group generated by $S$ by its normal subgroup $N$ generated by the relation. $f$ induces a morphism $g:F(S)\rightarrow H$, it factors by $G$ if and only if its kernel contains $N$. This is equivalent to saying that  $g(r_i)=1$.

Comment: Do you mean that $\phi(r_i) = 1$? $f$ is only defined on $S$. And that only shows the well defined homomorphism, or isomorphism?

Comment: I mean $g(r_i)=1$, $g$ is defined on $F(S)$.

Comment: I think I follow. Am I correct that this gives us that $G$ is isomorphic to $H$?

Comment: It is not always an isomorphism,  its kernel can be $G$.